# how can we can make Array of Array in python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am getting data in python like this

```
N/A,0E-11,0E-11,0E-11,@,N/A,0.0,0.0,0E-11,@
```

1 line contain data for 1 array like  `N/A,0E-11,0E-11,0E-11,`  this is array of 4 variables  `N/A`  , `0E-11` , `0E-11`  , `0E-11` . And I have separated both by `@`  I get all variables in loop like this

```
        results += cursor.fetchone()   //getting full line
         results+='@'   // giving @ after 1 array of data
    for r in results:     //iterating all variables 
        results_data.append(r)
        results_data.append(',')
    print results


Now I want to make a array of array like this   
 MainArray[ array[i] , array[i+1 ] , array[i+2] ]
```

like after @ new array and , a new attribute.

Comment: Why are you adding '@' if you then want to remove it again?

Comment: @Holloway then how to keep track that  1 array data is  completed   and new array should be made ?

Comment: Assuming `cursor.fetchone()` returns one array, just add that to a list?

Comment: @Holloway yes It is , Then How I can push in array of array ? like a array containing  array[i] data where i is dynamic ?

Comment: Does your database table contain _one_ column with the column-separated data you show, or are they in separate columns?

Comment: @Holloway   MainArray[ array[i] , array[i+1 ] , array[i+2] ]    I need something like this

Comment: "Same column" and "spaces between them" are opposite things. How about you show the query? This is getting nowhere.

Comment: @alexis diff columns

Comment: Then try my code already! Any version. You are making it too difficult, getting what you describe is exactly what database APIs do.

Comment: Wait, does your code actually have `results += "@"` and it doesn't give you an error? Then `results` is a string, not a list. What did you _actually_ do? I give up.

Comment: Yes i added It manually Sir 
To identify rows sepreatly

Comment: Produce a [mcve]. Include the query you're issuing, your table schema, and some sample data. It'd seem you're trying to query strings of comma separated values, but it's a bit unclear, and this might be an XY problem.

Comment: `fetchone()` returns a tuple, and you cannot add a string to a tuple. If you have working code, this is not it. This question makes no sense and needs to be closed until you can figure out, and explain, what you are doing.

Comment: @Ilja just vote to close, this is hopeless. I'm out of here (But I might respond if I see something that makes sense.)

Comment: @alexis Voted already, just leaving a note why.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the `results` arrays into a list, instead of adding their elements one by one. This will give you a list of lists:

```
...
array3.append(results)
```

You can also streamline your code by appending the array returned by the database (no point in joining and splitting it again), and iterating over the cursor (which is equivalent to calling `fetchone()`):

```
array3 = list()
for row in cursor:
    array3.append(row)
```

In fact, Python is so nicely put together that you can do this in one step:

```
array3 = list(cursor)
```

Or you could simply use `cursor.fetchall()`. That's what it is for. Ain't Python great?

```
array3 = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: I want to create dynamic array of array SIr

Comment: Also it's called "list" in Python.

Comment: Then How I can push it  in array of array ? like a array containing array[i] data where i is dynamic ?  MainArray[ array[i] , array[i+1 ] , array[i+2] ]

Comment: Try my code already. It does what you are asking for... as far as I can tell.